# How to find highest count of result set using multiple tables in SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have four tables. Here are the skeletons...

```
ACADEMIC_TBL
    academic_id
    academic_name


AFFILIATION_TBL
    academic_id*
    institution_id*
    joined_date
    leave_date

INSTITUTION_TBL
    institution_id
    institution_name

REVIEW_TBL
    academic_id*
    institution_id*
    date_posted
    review_score
```

Using these tables I need to find the academic (displaying their name, not ID) with the highest number of reviews and the institution name (not ID) they are currently affiliated with. I imagine this will need to be done using multiple sub-select scripts but I'm having trouble figuring out how to structure it.

Comment: Please provide sample data and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work:

```
SELECT   at.academic_name, 
         it.institution_name, 
         Max(rt.review_score), 
from     academic_tbl at, 
         affiliation_tbl afft, 
         institution_tbl it, 
         review_tbl rt 
WHERE    AT.academic_id=afft.academic_id 
AND      afft.institution_id=it.institution_id 
AND      afft.academic_id=rt.academic_id 
GROUP BY at.academia_name,it.instituton_id
```

Comment: It is likely that this query will generate an error because some of the SELECTed columns do not belong to the GROUP BY clause

Comment: You should really stop using those ancient and fragile implicit joins in the WHERE clause and start using "modern" (more than 25 years old) explicit JOIN operators

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i dont use modern i am used to ancient joins syntax that works in my office i cant help it . My manager has asked me to use old syntax only.

Answer (score 0):

You need an aggregated query that JOINs all 4 tables to count how many reviews were performed by each academic.

Query :

```
SELECT
    inst.institution_name, 
    aca.academic_name, 
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    academic_tbl aca
    INNER JOIN affiliation_tbl aff ON aff.academic_id = aca.academic_id
    INNER JOIN institution_tbl inst ON inst.institution_id = aff.institution_id
    INNER JOIN review_tbl rev ON rev.academic_id = aca.academic_id AND rev.institution_id = aff.institution_id
GROUP BY
    inst.institution_name, 
    aca.academic_name,
    inst.institution_id, 
    aca.academic_id
```

NB :

- added the academic and institution id to the GROUP BY clause to prevent potential academics or institutions having the same name from being (wrongly) grouped together
- if the same academic performed reviews for different institutions, then you will find one row for each academic / institution couple, which, if I understood you right, is what you want

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
select
       inst.institution_name
     , aca.academic_name
from
       academic_tbl    aca
     , institution_tbl inst
     , affiliation_tbl aff
     , review_tbl      rev
     , (
              select
                     max(rt.review_score) max_score
              from
                     review_tbl      rt
                   , affiliation_tbl aff_inn
              where
                     rt.date_posted     >= aff_inn.join_date
                     and rt.date_posted <= aff_inn.leave_date
                     and rt.academic_id = aff_inn.academic_id
                     and rt.institution_id  = aff_inn.institution_id
       )
       agg
where
       aca.academic_id         = inst.academic_id
       and inst.institution_id = aff.institution_id
       and aff.institution_id  = rev.institution_id
       and aff.academic_id     = rev.academic_id
       and rev.date_posted    >= aff.join_date
       and rev.date_posted    <= aff.leave_date
       and rev.review_score    = agg.max_score
;
```

It might return more than one academic, if there are more with the same score (maximum one).